# How to pipe value to another observable creator without cancelling original stream?

Tags: angular, rxjs

What I wanted to do is to implement suggestion box for the UI. The goal here is to listen to input changes, filter them out, pass them to service call and return results.

What I did is

```
this.sub = this.form.controls['host'].valueChanges
      .pipe(
        tap(console.log),
        filter((v) => v != null && v.length),
        debounceTime(500),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        switchMap(v => this.hostService.suggest(v)) //actuall REST call
      ).subscribe(value => {
        this.hostSuggestions = value;
      });
```

however, this does REST call only once, and stops reacting after that. As a workaround I am doing this

```
this.sub = this.form.controls['host'].valueChanges
  .pipe(
    tap(console.log),
    filter((v) => v != null && v.length),
    debounceTime(500),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    // switchMap(v => this.hostService.suggest(v))
  ).subscribe(value => {
    this.hostService.suggest(value).subscribe(hosts => this.hostSuggestions = value);
  });
```

and it works fine, but I think it can be done using pure operators. Am I correct?

Comment: If there is no error handling in the inner observable: `this.hostService.suggest(v)`. If the first call returns an error, it will cause the outer observable to also error and complete, thus not emitting any more values

Comment: okay, indeed I was testing this on non existent endpoint thus with errors - so you are saying it should work with `switchMap` just like that?? I will definetly check that

Comment: Yes, you can try it with a creation observable like: `switchMap(v => of('test'))`

Comment: I just checked and it does not work - event without errors REST call is done only once.

Comment: I think the difference is that http observable actually completes after emmiting value while `of` does not.

Comment: I just tested it in stackblitz and it seems to work. Take a look: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-issue-repro2-xn7w9z

Comment: Hmm indeed it works on stackblitz and looks exactly the same as my code. What the hell?

Comment: @Antoniossss Something that I noticed in your code is that you're trying to sync the variable `hostSuggestions` inside a subscription. In stackblitz I used async pipe instead.

Comment: You know what, I think I had some errors in the console and that was breaking the app. I have missed those because I was looking at network tab in the Firefox. It works with `switchMap` as I thought it should in the first place. Thanks for the effort. If you create an answer I can accept it :)

Comment: As a bonus question - since errors (on service call) can potentially breake whole pipe, how to countermeasure that? Return empty observable on error?

Comment: For the last question: I would just use `catchError` in the inner `observable` and return `EMPTY`. See it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-issue-repro2-54szgi)

Comment: Thats what I had in mind. Thank you very much!.

Answer (score 0):

Change switchMap for a mergeMap. when the observable in switchMap operator emit the first value cancel the subscription of previous observable.

Comment: Why would I use mergeMap if I am not interested in values that comes from input?

Comment: you need make a http request when the the value of host input change. if u use merge map you keep listen on input changes and you will trigger a http call each time and in your .subscribe u will recive the hostService response.. with a switch map you cancel the valueChanges subscription after the first emission of the hostService

Comment: To be honest, it works with `switchMap` - just like on first snippet (and how I was expecting in the first place). The reason why it was not working was probably due to other appplication errors I didnt see on console because I was looking on network tab (then console is hidden). Are you saying it should not work?